# Extract latitude and longitude from coordinates

Tags: python, google-maps, gps

I have this sort of data, and I want to extract the latitude and longitude in Python.

```
col[index]=
52.420223333,-1.904525
52.420221667,-1.904531667
52.420221667,-1.904536667
52.42022,-1.904545
52.420218333,-1.904553333
52.420216667,-1.904556667
```

I know how to do this in PHP, but wasn't sure how to implement it in Python:

```
sscanf($string, '"(%f, %f)"', $lat, $lng);
```

EDIT:
This code runs and outputs the coordinates above

```
for index in range(len(col)):
    print col[index]
```

In the for loop, is it possible to get the lat and long data. e.g. for the first iteration, lat=52.420223333 and lon=-1.904525.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for index in range(len(col)):
    lat, lon = col[index].split(",")
    print "lat=%s, lon=%s" % (lat, lon)
```

Comment: But it doesn't output the latitude and longitude data separately e.g. for the first iteration, lat=52.420223333 and lon=-1.904525.