# extract latitude and longitude from given input

Tags: python

I want to extract the latitude and longitude from the given input

```
input=-6.00753745047,53.4988487471 -6.00649712382,53.4977981241 -6.00788849553,53.4962929888 -6.00660721705,53.4967836409
```

Here is the code I tried but giving no output

```
for pos in range(len(input)):
 lt,lo=input[pos].split(',')
  print "lat is:",lt , "and long is:",lo
```

Comment: var `input` is only a tuple?

Comment: It's not even a tuple; as presented, it's a syntax error. The code would work with `input=['-6.00753745047,53.4988487471', '-6.00649712382,53.4977981241', '-6.00788849553,53.4962929888', '-6.00660721705,53.4967836409']`. `for pos in input: lt, lo = pos.split(',')` would be superior, though.

Comment: Assuming `input` is a string: `print "\n".join("lat:{0}, long:{1}".format(lat,long) for lat,long in map(lambda ll: ll.split(','), input.split())`

Comment: @chepner better to make it an answer ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract latitude and longitude from coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870765/extract-latitude-and-longitude-from-coordinates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If`input`is really a long string:

```
input = "-6.00753745047,53.4988487471 -6.00649712382,53.4977981241 " + \
        "-6.00788849553,53.4962929888 -6.00660721705,53.4967836409"

for lt, lo in (pair.split(',') for pair in input.split()):
    print "lat is:", lt, "and long is:", lo
```

Output:

```
lat is: -6.00753745047 and long is: 53.4988487471
lat is: -6.00649712382 and long is: 53.4977981241
lat is: -6.00788849553 and long is: 53.4962929888
lat is: -6.00660721705 and long is: 53.4967836409
```

`lt`and`lo`will be string values using this. If you'd like numeric values to do computations with instread, they can be converted in the same`for`loop with this:

```
for lt, lo in (map(float, pair.split(',')) for pair in input.split()):
    ...
```

Comment: The `+ \ ` part can be omitted.

Comment: @Andrei: Only if the whole thing was enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: I wasn't very exact with my comment. In the above code `+` can be omitted and if the variable contents had been enclosed in parenthesis, `+ \ ` could have been omitted.